# Picture changes size rapidly on tablet

Tags: responsive-design, tablet, image-size

Good day everybody,

I´ve build a website on Desktop wich should be responsive. As I wanted to test it on tablet the pictures start changing their size none stop from big to small and from small to big. One desktop everything works fine but on Ipad and Android tablet the pictures are changing sizes all the time. It looks very flickery.

If someone knows this bug or knows where to look for it, please tell me. I would appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It had something todo with the size of the textbox next to it.

Comment: you should accept your own answer, or delete the question